# postgresql json array index

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, indexing

I have data for customers with more than one adresses with json representation like this:

```
{
    "firstName" : "Max",
    "lastName" : "Mustermann",
    "addresses" : [{
            "city" : "München",
            "houseNumber" : "1",
            "postalCode" : "87654",
            "street" : "Leopoldstraße",
        }, {
            "city" : "Berlin",
            "houseNumber" : "2a",
            "postalCode" : "12345",
            "street" : "Kurfürstendamm",
        }
    ]
}
```

these json is stored in a column named json of datatype json in a table named customer.

I want to query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer cust, 
     json_array_elements(cust.json#>'{addresses}') as adr 
WHERE adr->>'city' like '%erlin' 
and adr->>'street' like '%urf%';
```

Query works fine ... but can't create index that postgresql 9.3.4 can use.

Any idea?

Comment: _Any idea?_ Normalize it.

Comment: "column named json of datatype json" it is a bad idea to name a column with its type name.

Comment: You can try to use full text search on the whole JSON but this idea is not that good. You can even try to build full text search on subset of the JSON but it is rather hard. The best way to handle it - normalize and use FTS of specific columns.

Comment: PostgreSQL can't index that usefully - or at least not without some ugly hacks with expression indexes. 9.4 will be able to, with `jsonb`.